# Is there a maximum number of repetition when using recursion?

Tags: c, recursion

I m trying to make a sudoku solver,with basic knowledge,using recursion.It solved sudoku puzzles i entered as long as the number of repetition is less than 3485/3500.Every time it fails it fails somewhere around that number.So i was wondering is there a threshold or is it my mistake?

Comment: Recursion is not repetition. You should check the memory usage of your program while running it.

Comment: The term you're looking for is `maximum recursion depth`, and that number depends on the stack size.

Comment: You are welcome to have a look at [my Sudoku solver code on GitHub](https://github.com/jselbie/SudokuSolver). It does not use recursion.

Answer (score 3):

Each call takes some stack space. When you call things recursively, the first call is still going on while the second one starts, so you are using stack space for 2 calls. If call#2 makes call#3 then your stack contains 3 calls and so on.

The recursion limit is based on how much stack you have.

Comment: So only way to fix this problem is to make more efficient code?

Comment: @user11616868 - you can save stack space by using less number of parameters per function call.  Even better, stop using recursion altogether and use your own stack based data structure that allocates memory from the heap.

Comment: @user11616868 not the "only" way.

Comment: you can also increase your allowed stack space. for instance if you are on linux and running the program through bash you can see your stack limit with ulimit -s and set it with ulimit -s <num_bytes>